# Journals or Articles for under graduates.

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, education

I am teaching to under-grads and many students asked me to refer some journals or articles which are accessible to them. It would be great if our community helps me out by giving links to journals consisting of  interesting research articles , expository, survey articles, or interesting historical surveys of  concepts or theorems which can develop interest and mathematical maturity in under-grads. For now, I only know Resonance and MAA. Your help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I really hope this gets some answers. +1 :)

Comment: I am an undergraduate student. every time i ask this question from my teachers, they don't answer me clearly...